# Can I monitor multiple servers using Prometheus?

Tags: performance, monitoring, prometheus

I want to monitor different servers for my entreprise and I'm going to use Prometheus for that, I want to know if I can monitor them?
example: I want to install Prometheus on a server and monitor the rest of servers using agents, but I dont find any documentations about Prometheus agents.
Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes you can. You need to install Prometheus on a server (see how to install [here](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/installation/)) and install "exporters" on the other servers (see a list of exporters [here](https://prometheus.io/docs/instrumenting/exporters/)). You could start installing the "Node Exporter" (see a good guide [here](https://prometheus.io/docs/guides/node-exporter/)). The "Node Exporter" exposes a wide variety of hardware and kernel-related metrics to Prometheus.